# Differences in delegate creation syntax

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, lambda, delegates

I can use either of the following:

```
var alert = new Action<string>((s) => MessageBox.Show(s));

// Or

Action<string> alert = (s) => MessageBox.Show(s);

// Or

Action<string> alert = new Action<string>((s) => MessageBox.Show(s));
```

Is there any difference between them, from the perspective of the code generated by the C# compiler? Or is it just a matter of taste?

Comment: Wow, down-voted because it is not about programming. Maybe you can also answer the question: **does compiler generate the same code or not?**

Comment: Downvotes and close votes aren't the same thing. It was *close* voted for the given reason, and downvoted because... who knows.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, I understand. I guess different people have different grasp of what programming is.

Comment: The close vote wasn't because someone thought this wasn't a programming question. The close reason was "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance." I don't think this close reason even applies here. This question is not about a coding problem, but about the behavior of the C# compiler. It's a perfectly legitimate question for this site, IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no difference. The generated IL in all three cases is identical. If you're curious, here's what LINQPad generated (using `Console.WriteLine` as a stand-in for `MessageBox.Show`):

```
IL_0000:  ldsfld      UserQuery.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1
IL_0005:  brtrue.s    IL_0018
IL_0007:  ldnull      
IL_0008:  ldftn       b__0
IL_000E:  newobj      System.Action<System.String>..ctor
IL_0013:  stsfld      UserQuery.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1
IL_0018:  ldsfld      UserQuery.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1

b__0:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0006:  ret
```

However, there is a fourth syntax that *is* different:

```
Action<string> alert = MessageBox.Show;
```

The previous examples all create a delegate by generating an anonymous method, and binding to it. This new syntax binds the delegate *directly* to the original method. The generated IL in this case is:

```
IL_0000:  ldnull      
IL_0001:  ldftn       System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0007:  newobj      System.Action<System.String>..ctor
```

Comment: An awesome answer, +1 and will be accepted as soon as SO allows me.